# Woocommerce: Show related products nested

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have client who would like to have different related products, the related products will be manually added into woocommerce.

The issue it that the related products is showing randomly, and we would like to be able to show related products nested by the categories - like this:

Related products from catergory 1

Related products from catergory 2

Related products from catergory 3

Is there a way to do this?